# Scheduler in or outside Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, spring-scheduled

We need to create simple email schedule process that run every day at 6AM. We have two choice:

1. Setup a scheduler in AWS Lambda that basically trigger event which run the job. High maintenance.
2. Setup scheduler task within Spring Boot using a cron expression. Low maintenance.

Which option is better and preferred. I personally prefer #2.

Design a schedule task

Comment: Without any specific buisness demands this question is mostly opinionated. As ”better ” is a subjective opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello!**

Either work fine for scheduled tasks, AWS Lambda could possibly start up a bit slower compared to Spring Boot, but shouldn't be too obvious.

In the end it's whichever you'd like to use and whichever is easier for you, in this case it seems like Spring Boot. So I'd go with that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have spring boot running on a server 24/7 then using Spring Boot scheduler is probably an easier and cleaner solution. Just remember if you are running multiple Spring Boot servers you should configure Spring to use a database backend for the Quartz scheduler.

If you do not have a Spring Boot server running 24/7, then it's going to be cheaper to use a scheduled Lambda function or an ECS Scheduled Task.